# Xcode UIImageView rounded corners doesn't work

Tags: xcode, uiimageview

I wanted to have an UIImageView appear with rounded corners, and found the following code to do it on Stack Overflow:

```
loginImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"BlueSky.jpg"]];
CALayer *l = [loginImage layer];
[l setMasksToBounds:YES];
[l setCornerRadius:5.0];

[loginImage release];
```

I added this code to my viewDidLoad method, but unfortunately the UIImageView does not give me  the rounded corners I was expecting. I linked the imageview "loginImage" correctly in Interface Builder.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here? 
Thanks!

Comment: weird, but try [l setCornerRadius:5.0f]; Does your project include important frameworks such as <QuartzCore/CALayer.h> or <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but unfortunately it didn't work... I also don't get any error messages when the view loads... Yes it includes the needed frameworks..

Comment: well, if the code here is full, how the program knows that this is the subview? you should add something like this
loginImage.layer = l; or even avoid making extra objects;

[loginImage.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
[loginImage.layer setCornerRadius:5.0f];

Comment: On your advice, I replaced: CALayer *l = [loginImage layer] by CALayer *l = loginImage.layer; but without positive result (although still without errors)... I declared the loginImage in the .h file as an IBOutlet UIImageView and linked it to the Files Owner in Interface Builder...

Comment: no no no, not l = [loginImage Layer]; but loginImage.layer = l; these are two different lines.

Comment: Oh, thanks man... I deleted the first line (UIImage view memory allocation) and now it works... (Very strange...) Héhé, but I kept the line  *l = loginImage.layer... don't know if it's normal that it works though

Comment: and why are you releasing your loginImage after these steps?
and yes, why did you allocated the UIImageView if it is already created by IB:)

Comment: Because I allocated memory, I thought to release the memory? I'm a beginner, but I thought this was the way to do it...

Comment: Yeah, haha I didn't know if it was necessary, but I wouldn't believe that it would hurt if the allocation was there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create your UIImageView with Interface Builder, you actually do not need to create it manually in code.

So, if you create your UIImageView with IB, the code should look like this.

```
CALayer *l = [loginImage layer];
[l setMasksToBounds:YES];
[l setCornerRadius:5.0];
loginImage.layer = l;
```

also, for beginners is good to read [memory management](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MemoryManagement.html)

Comment: Ok, now I see your point and I will accept your answer. I actually did: CALayer *l = loginImage.layer; in one line. I suppose it's valid? And shouldn't I have released the loginImage in case I would have manually allocate memory to it? I read the course about memory management, it's actually where I learned it from...

Comment: you should release YOUR objects when you do not need them anymore. for example, this is usually made in -(void)dealloc; method. So, if you need your loginImage you do not need to release it yet.

Comment: with line CALayer* l = loginImage.layer; you equate your loginImage.layer to l not vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(UIImage *)makeRoundedImage:(UIImage *) image 
                      radius: (float) radius;
{
  CALayer *imageLayer = [CALayer layer];
  imageLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
  imageLayer.contents = (id) image.CGImage;

  imageLayer.masksToBounds = YES;
  imageLayer.cornerRadius = radius;

  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);
  [imageLayer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
  UIImage *roundedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

  return roundedImage;
}
```